# Node Debug how to set DEBUG in the code

Tags: node.js

I want to use debug module in my app
instead of console.log or like that 
but without run my app with:

```
DEBUG=app node server
```

so I've tried like:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    process.env.DEBUG = 'app';
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to set up DEBUG mode in the code ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @thefourtheye (see comment)

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    process.env.DEBUG = 'app';
}
var debug = require('debug')('app');
```

**BETTER**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    process.env.DEBUG = 'app:*';
}
var debug = require('debug'),
    info = debug('app:info'),
    error = debug('app:error');
```

Comment: Are you requiring `debug` modules after this statement executed?

Comment: Yes, at the top of the script I've got var debug = require('debug')('app');

Comment: Move the `if` condition before requiring debug

Comment: @thefourtheye it works put the comment as reply, please :)